# script is unable to find the CDN

Tags: javascript, html, css, typedjs

I'm confused about how to use typejs CDN:

I put the CDN in the head of the HTML document and the scripts at the very end of the body but I get this error: (I think the script is unable to find the CDN!) Why?! Am I used the incorrect order to use the CDN or the script?

> Uncaught TypeError: Typed.new is not a function at
>   HTMLDocument.

Here is the code :

I have the CDN at the very beginning of the head tag:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typed.js/1.1.7/typed.min.js"></script>
```

And the script at the very end of the body:

```
<script src="typing.js"></script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="rtl">

<head>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/typed.js/1.1.7/typed.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Styles -->
    <link href="./TheSaaS — Responsive Bootstrap SaaS, Startup &amp; WebApp Template_files/page.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="./TheSaaS — Responsive Bootstrap SaaS, Startup &amp; WebApp Template_files/style.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Favicons -->
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="http://thetheme.io/thesaas/assets/img/apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="icon" href="http://thetheme.io/thesaas/assets/img/favicon.png">

    <!--  Open Graph Tags -->
    <meta property="og:title" content="TheSaaS">
    <meta property="og:description" content="A responsive, professional, and multipurpose SaaS, Software, Startup and WebApp landing template powered by Bootstrap 4.">
    <meta property="og:image" content="http://thetheme.io/thesaas/assets/img/og-img.jpg">
    <meta property="og:url" content="http://thetheme.io/thesaas/">
    <meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">

</head>

  <body data-aos-easing="ease" data-aos-duration="1500" data-aos-delay="0" data-gr-c-s-loaded="true" class="granim-light">

        <a class="btn btn-xs btn-round btn-success" href="https://themeforest.net/item/thesaas-responsive-bootstrap-saas-software-webapp-template/19778599?license=regular&amp;open_purchase_for_item_id=19778599&amp;purchasable=source&amp;ref=thethemeio">Buy Now</a>

      </div>
    </nav><!-- /.navbar -->


    <!-- Header -->
    <header class="header text-white h-fullscreen overflow-hidden" style="background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, #667eea 0%, #764ba2 100%);">
      <canvas class="constellation" data-radius="0" width="1536" height="763"></canvas>
      <div class="container position-static">
        <div class="row align-items-center h-100">

          <div class="col-lg-7">


            <h1 class="display-4 fw-500">

              <!-- Built For <span class="typeit fw-400 pl-2" data-typing="Startups, Entrepreneurs, Makers, Developers, SaaS, WebApp" data-type-speed="80">We</span><span class="typed-cursor">|</span> -->

              Built For <span class="type fw-400 pl-2"></span><span class="typed-cursor">|</span>

            </h1>


            <p class="lead mt-5 mb-7 mb-md-9 w-80">

              <strong>TheSaaS</strong> is an elegant, modern and fully customizable SaaS and WebApp template powered by Bootstrap 4

            </p>

            <a class="btn btn-xl btn-round btn-success w-200 mr-3 px-6 d-none d-md-inline-block" href="https://themeforest.net/item/thesaas-responsive-bootstrap-saas-software-webapp-template/19778599?license=regular&amp;open_purchase_for_item_id=19778599&amp;purchasable=source&amp;ref=thethemeio">Buy Now — $39</a>
            <a class="btn btn-xl btn-round btn-outline-light w-200 px-6" href="http://thetheme.io/thesaas/#section-demo">Explore Demos</a>
          </div>

          <div class="col-lg-5 d-none d-lg-block">
          </div>

        </div>

        <div class="d-none d-lg-block sample-blocks">
          <a href="http://thetheme.io/thesaas/block/cover.html#block-2" target="_blank">
            <img class="shadow-6 aos-init aos-animate" src="./TheSaaS — Responsive Bootstrap SaaS, Startup &amp; WebApp Template_files/block-1.jpg" alt="..." data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="0" data-aos-offset="0">
          </a>

          <a href="http://thetheme.io/thesaas/block/team.html#block-6" target="_blank">
            <img class="shadow-6 aos-init aos-animate" src="./TheSaaS — Responsive Bootstrap SaaS, Startup &amp; WebApp Template_files/block-2.jpg" alt="..." data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="200" data-aos-offset="0">
          </a>

          <a href="http://thetheme.io/thesaas/block/cover.html#block-5" target="_blank">
            <img class="shadow-6 aos-init aos-animate" src="./TheSaaS — Responsive Bootstrap SaaS, Startup &amp; WebApp Template_files/block-3.jpg" alt="..." data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="400" data-aos-offset="0">
          </a>

          <a href="http://thetheme.io/thesaas/block/blog.html#block-1" target="_blank">
            <img class="shadow-6 aos-init aos-animate" src="./TheSaaS — Responsive Bootstrap SaaS, Startup &amp; WebApp Template_files/block-4.jpg" alt="..." data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="600" data-aos-offset="0">
          </a>

          <a href="http://thetheme.io/thesaas/block/feature.html#block-8" target="_blank">
            <img class="shadow-6 aos-init aos-animate" src="./TheSaaS — Responsive Bootstrap SaaS, Startup &amp; WebApp Template_files/block-5.jpg" alt="..." data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="800" data-aos-offset="0">
          </a>

          <a href="http://thetheme.io/thesaas/block/feature.html#block-13" target="_blank">
            <img class="shadow-6 aos-init aos-animate" src="./TheSaaS — Responsive Bootstrap SaaS, Startup &amp; WebApp Template_files/block-6.jpg" alt="..." data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="1000" data-aos-offset="0">
          </a>

          <a href="http://thetheme.io/thesaas/block/shop.html#block-4" target="_blank">
            <img class="shadow-6 aos-init aos-animate" src="./TheSaaS — Responsive Bootstrap SaaS, Startup &amp; WebApp Template_files/block-7.jpg" alt="..." data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="1200" data-aos-offset="0">
          </a>

          <a href="http://thetheme.io/thesaas/block/feature-text.html#block-3" target="_blank">
            <img class="shadow-6 aos-init aos-animate" src="./TheSaaS — Responsive Bootstrap SaaS, Startup &amp; WebApp Template_files/block-8.jpg" alt="..." data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="1400" data-aos-offset="0">
          </a>

          <a href="http://thetheme.io/thesaas/block/pricing.html#block-6" target="_blank">
            <img class="shadow-6 aos-init aos-animate" src="./TheSaaS — Responsive Bootstrap SaaS, Startup &amp; WebApp Template_files/block-9.jpg" alt="..." data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-delay="1700" data-aos-offset="0">
          </a>
        </div>

      </div>
    </header><!-- /.header -->

<div id="popup-funfact" class="popup p-4 w-300" data-animation="slide-up" data-position="bottom-left" data-autoshow="3000" data-autohide="15000">
  <h6>Fun Fact</h6>
  <p class="mb-0">This is the <mark>most popular</mark> technology template on Themeforest. <a href="https://themeforest.net/category/site-templates/technology?sort=sales" target="_blank">See Proof</a>.</p>
</div>

    <!-- Scripts -->
    <script type="text/javascript" async="" src="./TheSaaS — Responsive Bootstrap SaaS, Startup &amp; WebApp Template_files/f.txt"></script><script async="" src="./TheSaaS — Responsive Bootstrap SaaS, Startup &amp; WebApp Template_files/analytics.js.download"></script><script src="./TheSaaS — Responsive Bootstrap SaaS, Startup &amp; WebApp Template_files/page.min.js.download"></script><div class="pswp" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true"><div class="pswp__bg"></div><div class="pswp__scroll-wrap"><div class="pswp__container"><div class="pswp__item"></div><div class="pswp__item"></div><div class="pswp__item"></div></div><div class="pswp__ui pswp__ui--hidden"><div class="pswp__top-bar"><div class="pswp__counter"></div><button class="pswp__button pswp__button--close" title="Close (Esc)"></button> <button class="pswp__button pswp__button--share" title="Share"></button> <button class="pswp__button pswp__button--fs" title="Toggle fullscreen"></button> <button class="pswp__button pswp__button--zoom" title="Zoom in/out"></button><div class="pswp__preloader"><div class="pswp__preloader__icn"><div class="pswp__preloader__cut"><div class="pswp__preloader__donut"></div></div></div></div></div><div class="pswp__share-modal pswp__share-modal--hidden pswp__single-tap"><div class="pswp__share-tooltip"></div></div><button class="pswp__button pswp__button--arrow--left" title="Previous (arrow left)"></button> <button class="pswp__button pswp__button--arrow--right" title="Next (arrow right)"></button><div class="pswp__caption"><div class="pswp__caption__center"></div></div></div></div></div>
    <script src="./TheSaaS — Responsive Bootstrap SaaS, Startup &amp; WebApp Template_files/script.js.download"></script>

  

<style type="text/css" data-typed-js-css="true">
        .typed-cursor{
          opacity: 1;
        }
        .typed-cursor.typed-cursor--blink{
          animation: typedjsBlink 0.7s infinite;
          -webkit-animation: typedjsBlink 0.7s infinite;
                  animation: typedjsBlink 0.7s infinite;
        }
        @keyframes typedjsBlink{
          50% { opacity: 0.0; }
        }
        @-webkit-keyframes typedjsBlink{
          0% { opacity: 1; }
          50% { opacity: 0.0; }
          100% { opacity: 1; }
        }
      </style>


      <script src="typing.js"></script>
      <script src="./TheSaaS — Responsive Bootstrap SaaS, Startup &amp; WebApp Template_files/f(1).txt"></script>


    </body>

    </html>
```

And here is the script:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    Typed.new('.type', {
    strings: ["neighbor", "family", "team", "community"],
    stringsElement: null,
    // typing speed
    typeSpeed: 60,
    // time before typing starts
    startDelay: 600,
    // backspacing speed
    backSpeed: 20,
    // time before backspacing
    backDelay: 500,
    // loop
    loop: true,
    // false = infinite
    loopCount: 5,
    // show cursor
    showCursor: false,
    // character for cursor
    cursorChar: "|",
    // attribute to type (null == text)
    attr: null,
    // either html or text
    contentType: 'html',
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

While I've never heard of this library, let alone used it, it is immediately apparent from the [docs](https://github.com/mattboldt/typed.js/blob/master/README.md) that you're using it wrong: it should be `new Typed(...)` (using `Typed` as a constructor), not `Typed.new(...)` as you are. The `Typed` function object clearly has no `new` property , which explains the error you're getting.

If the problem had been that the library hadn't loaded, as you seem to think, then the error would have been different. Then `Typed` would be `undefined`, and the reported error would have been about trying to access a property of `undefined`. The actual error means that `Typed` exists but the `new` property isn't a function (such errors often mean the "not a function" value is `undefined`). The distinction may seem subtle but such reasoning can often help narrow down the source of an error.

Comment: But the constructor is correct here is the script and cdn that I used in action: https://codepen.io/team/movement/pen/xdvXMd

Comment: Using `new Typed` solved the problem... But why the above codepen works with the old constructor?

Comment: And also you're really skilled programmer. Aren't you?!

Comment: Haha, not sure about "really skilled", but I do my best. Happy to have helped - and genuinely not sure why your codepen is working as it appears to use the exact same version of the library, I might see if I can figure it out when I'm on my laptop later.

Comment: So as far as I can tell from trawling the Github repository and inspecting the CDN sources, it seems that `Typed.new` was what worked in v1, then when the library was updated to v2 this changed to `new Typed`. Your codepen is using v1.1.7 so that's why it works. This of course also means that the CDN link you show in your original question should work with `Typed.new` - are you sure that you were using that version and not some 2.x.x version? (It appears v2 is around 3 years old so there shouldn't really be an excuse to use the old version!)